# Взлом социальной страницы

Tags: пароль, взлом, соцсети, брутфорс

У меня две страницы в инстаграм с одним и тем же паролем. На одной вход совершен, на второй нет. На странице, через которую совершен вход есть возможность подобрать пароль во вкладке изменения пароля, как я поняла там не ограниченно количество раз ввода. Методом подбора выяснить пароль возможно, но вопрос где взять программу или код со всеми возможными вариациями. Использовала сложный пароль с спец.символами. Выяснив вход на одной странице, узнаю его и войду на вторую

Comment: А то что это противозаконно вас не смущает?

Comment: Не думаю что соцсеть типа инстаграм даст вам брутфорсить его изнутри. Скорее всего через несколько попыток вы получите капчу, потом вас заблокируют. А если прям все равно хотите, попробуйте писать расширение для страницы или запустите код прямо в консоль.